# How to pass a variable value to tree node label using java

Tags: java, jsp, treeview, struts

Below is my sample.jsp code for static tree structure.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<html>
<body>
<sx:tree id="books" label="Courses" title="test" >
<sx:treenode label="JAVA" title="test">
<sx:treenode label="PHP" title="test">
</sx:treenode>
</sx:treenode>
</sx:tree>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working but I want to pass a dynamic value to the sx:treenode label, I have tried

```
String s="SQL";
```

`<sx:treenode label="" title="test">${s}</sx:treenode>` but it is not displaying s value.

Can you please suggest me how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: What about the more logical `<sx:treenode label="${s}" title="test">`? Are you aware that the EL doesn't care about local variables, and only cares about attributes. Use `<c:set var="s" value="SQL"/>` before your tree.

Comment: @JBNizet Looks like a nice answer there...

Comment: I was too lazy to check the doc of sx:treenode, so I just posted it as a comment, as I'm not sure it accepts expressions (althought I would be surprised if it didn't).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the attribute in some scope. e.g. request scope or session scope like

```
 request.setAttribute("sql","yourSQL");
```

Then access it using `${requestScope.sql}`. Only scoped attributes are recognized for evaluation.

Comment: String value="JAVA";session.setAttribute("value",value);String s=(String)session.getAttribute("value");<sx:treenode label="">${s}</sx:treenode> i have tried like this but its not working.